# textfield with passwordMask or keyboardType set crashes on android

Tags: android, titanium-mobile

I've got a factory class that creates input windows on-the-fly for me. The reason for the creation of this factory class is to simplify the creation of input windows, as I have a lot of them. We are currently porting our app to android from iOS, and that's when we discovered this problem.

I'm trying the create a textfield like so:

```
  textField = Ti.UI.createTextField
    left: indentLeft
    right: 10
    color: "#336699"
    borderStyle: Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_NONE
    field: field
    hintText: field.hint
    value: field.value
    tag: field.name
    autocorrect: field.autocorrect
    autocapitalization: field.autocapitalization
    enabled: (field.enabled != false)
    keyboardType: field.keyboardType
    passwordMask: field.passwordMask
    returnKeyType: Ti.UI.RETURNKEY_DEFAULT
    textAlign: field.textAlign
```

This works perfectly fine on iOS, and the values specified by field.keyboardType and field.passwordMask are perfectly legal values according to the titianium docs. However, my android app crashes unless i comment out passwordMask AND keyboardType... Any idea why this would happen? Heres the android crashlog:

```
 E/TiApplication( 1216): (main) [249,918] Sending event: exception on thread: main msg:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to convert null to boolean.; Titanium 2.0.1,2012/04/12 16:36,999c68a
    E/TiApplication( 1216): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to convert null to boolean.
    E/TiApplication( 1216):     at org.appcelerator.titanium.util.TiConvert.toBoolean(TiConvert.java:342)
    E/TiApplication( 1216):     at org.appcelerator.titanium.util.TiConvert.toBoolean(TiConvert.java:355)
    E/TiApplication( 1216):     at ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.TiUIText.handleKeyboard(TiUIText.java:368)
    E/TiApplication( 1216):     at ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.TiUIText.processProperties(TiUIText.java:171)
    E/TiApplication( 1216):     at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollProxy.setModelListener(KrollProxy.java:737)
    E/TiApplication( 1216):     at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.realizeViews(TiViewProxy.java:530)
    E/TiApplication( 1216):     at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.handleGetView(TiViewProxy.java:522)
    E/TiApplication( 1216):     at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.getOrCreateView(TiViewProxy.java:500)
    E/TiApplication( 1216):     at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.forceCreateView(TiViewProxy.java:485)
    E/TiApplication( 1216):     at ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.tableview.TiTableViewRowProxyItem.refreshControls(TiTableViewRowProxyItem.java:133)
    E/TiApplication( 1216):     at ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.tableview.TiTableViewRowProxyItem.setRowData(TiTableViewRowProxyItem.java:280)
    E/TiApplication( 1216):     at ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.tableview.TiTableViewRowProxyItem.setRowData(TiTableViewRowProxyItem.java:84)
    E/TiApplication( 1216):     at ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.tableview.TiTableView$TTVListAdapter.getView(TiTableView.java:216)
    E/TiApplication( 1216):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
    E/TiApplication( 1216):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1727)
    E/TiApplication( 1216):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:652)
    E/TiApplication( 1216):     at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1284)
    E/TiApplication( 1216):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1570)
    E/TiApplication( 1216):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1147)
    E/TiApplication( 1216):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
    E/TiApplication( 1216):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
    E/TiApplication( 1216):     at ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.tableview.TiTableView.onLayout(TiTableView.java:516)
    E/TiApplication( 1216):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
    E/TiApplication( 1216):     at org.appcelerator.titanium.view.TiCompositeLayout.onLayout(TiCompositeLayout.java:519)
    E/TiApplication( 1216):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
    E/TiApplication( 1216):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
    E/TiApplication( 1216):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
    E/TiApplication( 1216):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
    E/TiApplication( 1216):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)
    E/TiApplication( 1216):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)
    E/TiApplication( 1216):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
    E/TiApplication( 1216):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
    E/TiApplication( 1216):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
    E/TiApplication( 1216):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1045)
    E/TiApplication( 1216):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
    E/TiApplication( 1216):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    E/TiApplication( 1216):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    E/TiApplication( 1216):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    E/TiApplication( 1216):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    E/TiApplication( 1216):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    E/TiApplication( 1216):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    E/TiApplication( 1216):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    E/TiApplication( 1216):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
D/dalvikvm( 1216): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 4053 objects / 380032 bytes in 77ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at org.appcelerator.titanium.util.TiConvert.toBoolean(TiConvert.java:342)

the above error indicates that in TiConvert.java class at line 342 you are trying to convert a null value to boolean check it.

Comment: I have... This only happens when passwordMask is not commented out, and the value passed to passwordMask is not null. i've tried several values, all non-null. still the same error.

Comment: Did you try to set true by hardcoding?

Comment: ahh, that actually worked, for some odd reason. The way I fixed it to not crash on android or iphone was to use passwordMask: (field.passwordMask === true)